# Add array to property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I'm trying to find a way to add an array to a property. Currently, I'm adding non-arrys with no trouble.

```cs
var root = JObject.Parse(contractJson.ToString());

//get company name node
var companyNameMatches = root.Descendants()
    .OfType<JObject>()
    .Where(x => x["question"] != null && x["question"].ToString() == "Name of the company");
//add answer result to company name node
foreach (JObject jo in companyNameMatches)
{
    jo.Add("answer", new JObject(new JProperty("result", Request.Form["Companyname"].ToString())));
}
```

So, this line...how to make "answer" into an array:

```cs
jo.Add("answer", new JObject(new JProperty("result", Request.Form["Companyname"].ToString())));
```

Looking for this output:

```
"answer":[ 
    { 
       "result": "value"
    }
 ]
```

Comment: Well you're currently setting it to a single string value - do you want it to be an array containing that single string? If so, have you tried doing just that? `new JProperty("result", new[] { Request.Form["Companyname"].ToString() })`

Comment: Hi, Jon. I should've been more descriptive. 

I'm looking for this:

```
"answer":[ 
    { 
       "result": "value"
    }
 ]
```

Comment: I suggest you edit the question further - you say you want to make "result" into an array, but you don't - you want to make *answer* into an array.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, thanks for pointing this out. I've made the suggested edit.

Answer (score 3):

You need your `answer` property to be an array, so you should use `JArray` for that. Change this line:

```
jo.Add("answer", new JObject(new JProperty("result", Request.Form["Companyname"].ToString())));
```

to:

```
// Create the object to put in the array
var result = new JObject(new JProperty("result", Request.Form["Companyname"].ToString()));
// Create the array as the value for the answer property
jo.Add("answer", new JArray { result });
```

Answer (score 0):

This because you are using `JObject`.

use the `JArray` object. A `JArray` is a `JContainer`, which is a JToken, which you can add to a `JObject`.

for example, json of users:

```
string[] parameterNames = new string[] { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };

JArray jarrayObj = new JArray();

foreach (string parameterName in parameterNames)
{
    jarrayObj.Add(parameterName);
}

string bDay = "2011-05-06";
string email = "dude@test.com";

JObject UpdateTestProfile = new JObject(
                               new JProperty("_delete", jarrayObj),
                               new JProperty("birthday", bDay),
                               new JProperty("email", email));

Console.WriteLine(UpdateTestProfile.ToString());
```